Why does adding a value to into() result cause type inference issues in Rust?
When I use into() to convert a u16 to a usize everything is fine:
fn main() {
    let vector_size = 10u16;
    let my_vector = vec![false; vector_size.into()];
}

but when I add a value to it, I get an error:
fn main() {
    let vector_size = 10u16;
    let my_vector = vec![false; vector_size.into() + 1usize];
}

The error:
error[E0283]: type annotations needed
 --> test.rs:3:45
  |
3 |     let my_vector = vec![false; vector_size.into() + 1usize];
  |                                             ^^^^
  |
  = note: cannot satisfy `_: From<u16>`
  = note: required for `u16` to implement `Into<_>`
help: try using a fully qualified path to specify the expected types
  |
3 |     let my_vector = vec![false; <u16 as Into<T>>::into(vector_size) + 1usize];
  |                                 +++++++++++++++++++++++           ~

error: aborting due to previous error

I wonder why the compiler can't infer the type even though I'm very specific. Is it something that could be solved in future updates, or is there a logical reason that I'm missing?

Rust supports operator overloading. It is possible to implement Add<usize, Output=usize> for an arbitrary type Foo.
This means that
let f = Foo::new();
let len = f + 1usize;
let my_vector = vec![false; len];

is valid.
If you return back to your vector_size.into() call, what you are asking rust to do is convert a u16 into 'a type that you can add 1usize to to get another usize'. This is not possible to infer.
In the first version there is no + and therefore no guesswork involved, you have a u16 and need a usize and rust can do that conversion.
